# Spring MVC - add cookie inside onBindAndValidate

Tags: servlets, cookies, spring-mvc

I'm currently working with a legacy Spring 2.5 application and what I'd like to do is to modify a custom controller's (which extends SimpleFormController) validation logic.

```
protected void onBindAndValidate(HttpServletRequest request, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception;
```

What I'd like to do inside this method is to write a cookie depending on the result of a service class I was provided with. However, since at this point inside the controller's workflow I do not have access to the `HttpServletResponse` object, is there any other way to:

- Either retrieve the `HttpServletResponse` object to write a cookie to it. Or.
- Use some other facility within Spring MVC to generate a cookie. I've looked at `org.springframework.web.util.CookieGenerator`, but it still requires a response object to work.

I appreciate the help anyone could provide.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that I still can't find any intuitive, built-in ways to do this from within Spring MVC 2.5.

So what I ended up doing is this hack. First I modified my controllers to invoke a utility function class that would take the resulting service object (wherever it may be invoked), which exposes a servlet compatible `getCookie()` method and then placed that under the user's session like so:

```
WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "myResponseObjectSessionName", myResponseObject);
```

Now, since they all inherit from `SimpleFormController`, I instead created a new abstract class which still inherits from the former, but has a modified `handleRequestInternal()` method, like so:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // let the controller do it's job
    ModelAndView result = handleRequestInternal(request, response, errors);

    // and then use a helper class to inspect the session, find the session attribute
    // 'myResponseObjectSessionName', and set any cookies left in case it does exist at 
    // this point in time.
    new ProcessServiceObject().setServiceResponseCookie(request, response);

    return result;
}
```

Not very elegant but I think it works. Cheers.